# Expectation of a random variable - Proof using MCT and simple functions

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, simple-functions

I got the following task:

**Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\rightarrow R$ a random variable with $X\geq0$  P-a.s. Prove that $E[X]=0$ implies that $X=0$ P-a.s.**

I tried to prove it using the monotone convergence theorem and simple functions. Is it a valid proof? If no, I would be glad for corrections or just hints.

Thank you

Note: i'm sure it is pretty sloppy, but this is my first ever attempt of a proof ever:)

---

Proof:
 Since $X$ is a discrete random variable, taking values $a_i$ = ($a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$), we have

\begin{equation}
X(\omega)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}a_iI_{A_i}(\omega)
\end{equation}

with $A_i\subseteq F$, $a_i\geq0$. Now let 
\begin{equation}
X_n(\omega)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}a_iI_{A_i}(\omega)
\end{equation}

be a sequence of measurable functions that converges to $X(\omega)$ P-a.s $\forall\omega\in\Omega$.

Thus, by the monotone convergence theorem:

\begin{align}
E(X) &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E(X_n)\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i P(A_i)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_iP(X=a_i).
\end{align}

Thus $E(X)=0$ implies $a_i=0$ P-a.s. and therefore $P(X=0)=1$ or $X=0$ P-a.s.

Comment: "Since X is a discrete random variable" Hmm... Where do they say this? (The part following this has major problems as well, but...)

Comment: You're right, thank you. Somehow I automatically assumed it was discrete. And what are those problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n>0$, note that
$$
P(X>1/n)\leq nE(X)=0
$$
by Chebyshev's inequality. In particular $P(X>0)=0$. Thus $X=0$ a.s.

Comment: "by Chebyshev's inequality" Actually, rather by Markov's inequality.